# How to determine the limit of $ f(x, y)=\frac{9xy}{x^2 + y^2}$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Given $$f(x,y) = \frac{9xy}{x^2 + y^2},$$ determine the limit of $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y) \to (2,1)$.
The answer for this would be $\dfrac{18}{5}$ right?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, indeed. Since a rational function is *continuous* over all points on which it is defined, and since clearly the function $f(x,y)$ is defined at $(2, 1)$ (and so too at all points other than $(0, 0))$, we have that
$$\lim_{(x, y) \to (2, 1)} \frac{9xy}{x^2 + y^2} = f(2, 1) = \dfrac{18}{5}.$$

Answer (score 0):

That's right.  Whenever you have a rational function (that is, a polynomial or the quotient of two polynomials), if you can plug in a point and get a value, then that value is also your limit.  This is true because rational functions (on any number of variables) are continuous over all points over which that function is defined.

However, this function may or may not have a limit at $(0,0)$, since $f(0,0)$ is undefined.  For this function, the limit at $(0,0)$ does not exist.